# Improving interface for compiling delegates from MemberInfo

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I work a lot with non-public third-party members in performance-critical cases, and to improve performance I made some extension methods to easily obtained compiled delegates from MemberInfo objects.

Example for `FieldInfo`:

```
public static TDelegate CompileUnboundFieldSetterDelegate<TDelegate>(this FieldInfo field) where TDelegate : Delegate
```

Usage:

```
public static readonly Action<TInstance, TField> SetMyField =
    typeof(TInstance).RequireField("myField").CompileUnboundFieldSetterDelegate<Action<TInstance, TField>>();
```

Where `RequireField(this Type type)` is just a wrapper on `GetField` that throws when not found.

But considering that I *know* this is a setter, and hence `TDelegate` must be `Action<TInstance, TField>`, and given that both `TInstance` and `TField` are encoded in the `FieldInfo`, my question is, could this interface be improved to avoid needing to pass the `TDelegate` parameter every time?

Something like:

```
public static Action<TInterface, TField> CompileUnboundFieldSetterDelegate<TInstance, TField>(this FieldInfo field)
```

would still require `TInterface` and `TField` be passed. On the other hand if I were to get both type from the field and return a generic `Delegate` I'd still have to perform a cast after calling the extension, which doesn't improve anything. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: not sure, what is wrong with `public static Action<TInterface, TField> CompileUnboundFieldSetterDelegate<TInstance, TField>(this FieldInfo field)`?

Comment: @GuruStron nothing wrong, but since the information is encoded in the `FieldInfo` instance I was wondering if it could be improved further.